# how to change at what header width the hamburger menu icon appears in the header?

Tags: media, at-command

I can't find where to edit the width at which the hamburger menu appears (when it switches from desktop to mobile header view). Right now it switches at 600px, i want to edit that.
here's the code, i'm not sure if that's the relevant part of the code though:

```
// Site drawer (mobile) variation

.site-header--drawer & {

position: fixed;
width: 370px;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
 right: 0;
    background: $colorDrawers;
padding: 75px;
display: block;

@include translate3d(370px, 0px, 0px);

&.opened {
@include translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
&.animate {
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
} 

@include at-query($max, $medium) {
 padding: 60px;
 }
 @include at-query($max, 370px) {
  width: 100%;
 }

ul {
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [header width at which the hamburger menu appears (where do i change it?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755887/header-width-at-which-the-hamburger-menu-appears-where-do-i-change-it)

Comment: Please do not repeat your questions.